# Mdbootstrap V5 input borders don't appear when used in AngularJS pages (other than layout)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to redesign some of the forms in an AngularJS application using mdbootstrap version 5. I've encountered a problem with inputs. The inputs that are inside pages of the dashboard (the app is a dashboard) don't get borders, whereas inputs that are on the main page or layout do.
I added the `mdb.js` file in my layout and it works fine. My assumption is that event listeners are registered before the elements are rendered so if that's correct I'm wondering if there is a way to re-register event listeners or recalculate styles somehow after the input elements are rendered.
[here are how my inputs loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FccOi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you described, I found this in mdbootstrap's own docs:

> If the input is dynamically loaded on the page, then after displaying it, the initialization should be performed as in the example below.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.form-outline').forEach((formOutline) => {
  new mdb.Input(formOutline).init();
});
```

source: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/input-fields/

Comment: I have similar issues, I tried the js code above, it works but only when I reload the page. If I move from one route to another for example /register to login, the border disappears then I have to hard reload the page to get it. Is this the normal behavior?